# SQL groups inside groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have transaction data like this example:

```
Name    | Price
George  | 20
George  | 20
George  | 20
George  | 30
Paul    | 20
Paul    | 20
Paul    | 30
Paul    | 30
Paul    | 35
```

I need to group by user and sort by the number of transactions in general, but within that group of users also make groups by price ordering by the amount of transactions at that price.
I need this result:

```
Name    | Price | Count
Paul    | 20    | 2
Paul    | 30    | 2
Paul    | 35    | 1
George  | 20    | 3
George  | 30    | 1
```

**UPDATE**

It is in a MySQL 5.5 database. I need to make the query for fluent in Laravel but having it in SQL is a great advance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You didn't say which DB you use which will limit how much we can help

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks, I updated my question, I use MySQL database.

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina Your comments are on point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ( SELECT name, 
              price, 
              COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM srctable
       GROUP BY name, price ) t1
JOIN ( SELECT name, 
              COUNT(*) tcnt
       FROM srctable
       GROUP BY name ) t2 USING (name)
ORDER BY tcnt DESC, 
         cnt DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4ef2a9e4ebf8baba127977714097d25)

Comment: Thanks Akina, your solution solves the problem. Unfortunately I need to do it using laravel's query builder and when I do a sub query the parameters are replaced wrong: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675900/laravel-query-builder-with-subquery-and-dynamic-filters)

Comment: @J_J Use raw SQL. Anycase you MUST use at least `select (db::raw` for fields aliasing...

Comment: @Akina Great solution. I would, however, use an explicit join instead of a natural join. The latter are error prone and obscure. +1

Comment: Another note, I would replace `ORDER BY tcnt DESC, cnt DESC` by `ORDER BY tcnt DESC, name, cnt DESC` to ensure stable ordering.

Comment: *The latter are error prone and obscure* In complex queries - maybe. But this is simple query without points for error. *to ensure stable ordering* OP says he need by total then by separate, so `name` in the middle do not match. Of course `ORDER BY tcnt DESC, cnt DESC, name` will give more stable ordering, but OP do not need in it, and I do not see the reason in forcing the server to do extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It can be done in MySQL 8.x. The double ordering you want requires the use of a couple of table expressions, as shown below:

```
select
  x.name, x.price, x.cnt
from (
  select name, price, count(*) as cnt
  from t
  group by name, price
) x
join (
  select name, row_number() over(order by cnt desc) as ob
  from (
    select name, count(*) as cnt
    from t
    group by name
  ) y
) z on x.name = z.name
order by z.ob, x.cnt desc
```

Result:

```
name    price  cnt
------  -----  ---
Paul       20    2
Paul       30    2
Paul       35    1
George     20    3
George     30    1
```

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table t (
  name varchar(10),
  price int
);

insert into t (name, price) values
  ('George', 20),
  ('George', 20),
  ('George', 20),
  ('George', 30),
  ('Paul', 20),
  ('Paul', 20),
  ('Paul', 30),
  ('Paul', 30),
  ('Paul', 35);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to sort the users by the total transactions and then by the amount of transactions at a price. If i do this: - SELECT name, price, count(*) as cnt from transaction group by name, price order by cnt desc - It will order only for the number of user transactions at a price, and I need you to order first for the total number of transactions regardless of the price.

Comment: @J_J Updated according to the ordering you need.